# VS2015 Check out files programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, vcs-checkout

I am using VS2015 and I try to check out files from a folder, that is included in a workspace: I have this mapping **D:\tfs** and I try to check out files from **D:\tfs\MyProject\Subfolder1**
I have added as references the **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client** and **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client v12** and used to

```
   TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(tfsServerAddress));
   var versionControl = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
   var workspace = versionControl.TryGetWorkspace(pathToFolder);
```

But it does not work, I always get **ItemNotMappedException**.

This is an old code that used to work with VS2010 and I assume TFS2010.
What is the newer approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make calling the API version independent.You need to use the same tfs client version to call the API.

Please try following below steps to fix the issue:

1. Remove current reference
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client and
   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
2. Install [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) by running
   the following command in the Package Manager Console

> PM > Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient
>   -Version 15.112.1

Then try it again.

You can also reference this similar thread to checkout the files:
[How can I programmatically check-out an item for edit in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097946/how-can-i-programmatically-check-out-an-item-for-edit-in-tfs)